# how to fetch multiple url and (how to verify if url is working before i fetch it) with js

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, fetch-api, promise.all

I have been looking at `Promise.all` for fetching multiple urls. I know that we can use `Promise.all` and pass an array there, and then fetch the content.

Let's say I have two URLs in an array but one of them is not working. How can I still use `Promise.all`? What is the other method fetching both? I would fetch both but if one of them is not working don't fetch the one that is not working.

```
const urls = [ instagramURL, facebookURL];

const thepromises = urls.map((url) => fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json()));
  Promise.all(thepromises).then((post) => {
  console.log(post);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your function with `try...catch` statments will help you `testing` a block of code for errors while the code being excuted. 
 
**for example,** you can try this :

```
const urls = [ instagramURL, facebookURL];

try {
      let promiseArray = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        promiseArray.push(fetch(urls[i]));
      }
     const results = Promise.all(promiseArray);
     console.log(results);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: You should a description/commentary on why you think this is a good answer that will solve the problem.

Comment: hey @Andy thanks for your comment, I have just updated my answer with your suggestions :)

Comment: Note that `fetch` also has a `catch` method so you may not need `try/catch`.

Comment: @OmarDieh and Andy thank for your answer.  i used bioth sugestion in some way.  so i  tried to make an url to give an error like on the code im goint to post right now . 
let promiseArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      promiseArray.push(fetch(urls[i]));
    }

      const results = Promise.all(promiseArray);

      results.then((items)=>{
     
      for(let item of items){
        
        if(item.status === 200){
          console.log(item)

        }

      }
     }).catch(error => console.log(error))

Comment: im being able to get the one with no error.  however on my console it showing another error on      promiseArray.push(fetch(urls[i]));   line. it is showing GET https://graph.facebook.com/ ...... 400 . i dont want to get the url with 400 status . how can i remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

use promise.allSettled[instagramURL, facebookURL]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).